# How do I change the iOS app distribution method from private to public in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Our app was initially submitted and granted for private distribution in App Store Connect. Now, we're interested in making it publicly available. Can you guide us on the steps to transition from private to public distribution?

We are expecting to finally successfully change from private to public.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a private app into a public app.

You can use your existing source code to create a new public app with a different bundle id